# Powershell, Missing a property in a column after creating it when trying to Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, export-csv

So, I'm trying to create a csv file and then append result data to it. I feel like I'm just misusing something here so I figured I'd ask.

```
$headerText = ('"SamAccountName","Password",' + "`n")
New-Item C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv | Add-Content -value $headerText

#stuff happens



Get-RandoPass| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv' -Append


Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv. The 
appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: 
SamAccountName. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and 
then retry the command.
At line:226 char:22
+ ... mPassword | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv'  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (SamAccountName:String) [Export-Csv], Inva 
   lidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.Po 
   werShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's treating the headers as one column header instead of two when you're outputting it - try without the single quotes when you output it.  Alternatively, don't add the header text, use export-csv with -append to simply add the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always, always create and test code paths that show results one step at a time, to make sure you are getting what you'd expect before moving to the next thing.

For example:
Why are you doing this?

```
$headerText = ('"SamAccountName","Password",' + "`n")
'New-Item D:\temp\test.csv' | Add-Content -value $headerText
```

If you wrote and tested just this section, you'd see right away that this approach is not prudent.

```
$headerText = ('"SamAccountName","Password",' + "`n")
'New-Item D:\temp\test.csv' | 
Add-Content -value $headerText -WhatIf
#Results
<#
Add-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:2 char:31
+ 'New-Item D:\temp\test.csv' | Add-Content -value $headerText -WhatIf
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (New-Item D:\temp\test.csv:String) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
#>
```

These are two separate commands, and as you can see, the pipeline is not possible. So, until you address that, nothing else matters.

```
$headerText = ('"SamAccountName","Password",' + "`n")
New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp' -Name test.csv -ItemType File -Force
Add-Content -Path 'D:\temp\test.csv' -Value $headerText -WhatIf


    Directory: D:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                
-a----         13-Aug-22     18:46              0 test.csv                                                                                                            
What if: Performing the operation "Add Content" on target "Path: D:\temp\test.csv".
```

***Refactor suggestion***

- You are overcomplicating this. There is no need for New-Item at all,
  as the ADDS cmdlets will have headers. You should really just combine
  the commands and output using the Export-Csv cmdlet.
- Don't use shorthand/aliases in scripts. It's bad practice and makes
  scripts hard to read and maintain. They are fine to use in throwaway
  code of interactive command line stuff.
- Take advantage of Powershell natural line break to avoid long code
  lines for better readability.

I do not have ADDS handy, but something like this should get you what you are after.

```
Get-ADDistinguishedName -ADComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach-Object{
    (($PSItem) -split ',' | 
    Where-Object {$PSItem -match '^DC'}) -join ','
}

Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -SearchBase $DNv | 
Select-Object SamAccountname, @{Name = 'Password';Expression = {Get-RandoPass}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'D:\temp\test.csv'
```

That formula is known as a PS calculated property. Take time to read up on them, as well as hash tables and PSCuistomObject to make your effort more efficient/proficient.

Combining output from multiple cmdlets is a common thing.

> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27combine+adds+cmdlet+output%27&t=h_&ia=web

***Update as per our comments below.***

```
# Generate one random password
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(15,2)
# Results
<#
_ruj5y1}jyHix1F
#>

# Generate one or more random passwords for user input
$PasswordCount = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox(
                    'Number of passwords needed:', 
                    'Generate Passwords', 
                    'Enter the number of passwords to generate here.'
                   )
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
1..$PasswordCount | 
ForEach-Object {[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(15,2)}
# Results
<#
!KE(b]2@h@s3iHt
?aZ[E()ElN-Q88R
liTKWM|UE/Dj&3;
aUP}r8n9bBJj]nY
PuQvOPs2f/QAi6?
#>
```

This can easily be turned into a proper function to call in other code.

```
Function New-RandomPassword 
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    #>

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('nrp')]

    Param
    (
    
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                            PresentationCore,
                            PresentationFramework,
                            System.Windows.Forms,
                            Microsoft.VisualBasic,
                            System.Web
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
 
        $PasswordCount = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::
                  InputBox(
                            'Number of passwords needed:', 
                            'Generate Passwords', 
                            'Enter the number of passwords to generate here.'
                           )

        1..$PasswordCount | 
        ForEach-Object {[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(15,2)}
}

Get-ADDistinguishedName -ADComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME | 
ForEach-Object{
    (($PSItem) -split ',' | 
    Where-Object {$PSItem -match '^DC'}) -join ','
}

Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -SearchBase $DNv | 
Select-Object SamAccountname, @{Name = 'Passwords';Expression = {New-RandomPassword}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'D:\temp\test.csv' -Append
```

Note:

This dialog box will show and ask for the number of passwords needed for every SamAccontname you pass to it. This is by design for any loop construct.

If you are after only asking the question once as input and for that number of passwords that are to be used for each SamAccountname passed in (which would be odd - as that is the same Passwords for everybody), then that function must be called standalone, the pass those results in the loop, not the function.

Meaning this:

```
$PasswordList = New-RandomPassword 

Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -SearchBase $DNv | 
Select-Object SamAccountname, @{Name = 'Passwords';Expression = {$PasswordList}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'D:\temp\test.csv' -Append
```

***Update based on your comment:***

```
Function Get-PasswordCount
{
    <#
    .Synopsis
       Short description
    .DESCRIPTION
       Long description
    .EXAMPLE
       Example of how to use this cmdlet
    .EXAMPLE
       Another example of how to use this cmdlet
    #>

    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    [Alias('gpc')]

    Param
    (
    
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                            PresentationCore,
                            PresentationFramework,
                            System.Windows.Forms,
                            Microsoft.VisualBasic,
                            System.Web
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
 
        [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::
                  InputBox(
                            'Passwords per SamAccountname', 
                            'Select random Passwords per account', 
                            'Enter the number of passwords to use per SamAccountname.'
                           )
}

# Do not put this in a loop, run separately
($PasswordList = New-RandomPassword)
# Results
<#
{BCE!xP@-QZbbW[
>i4F5/fFR;NOJ^r
xo>%u@.rR72Raf0
...
#>

# Do not put this in a loop, run separately
($SamAccountPasswordCount = Get-PasswordCount)
# Results
<#
5
#>

# This is in the loop
($SamAccountPasswordlist = $PasswordList | 
Get-Random -Count $SamAccountPasswordCount)
# Results
<#
(@rFcb|69SZR:n9
G7UiI?^bzu*Z!]1
bB>^])PxVI9q-VO
A6b_.J!gYF:7[o?
>i4F5/fFR;NOJ^r
#>


Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -SearchBase $DNv | 
Select-Object SamAccountname, @{Name = 'Passwords';Expression = {$SamAccountPasswordlist}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'D:\temp\test.csv' -Append
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this! I'm still very new to powershell and reading through powershell in a months worth of lunches! So looking it over that really does read a lot better than what I had written before.

With that said, Get-RandoPass has a variable that prompts the user for how many passwords to generate so it's on an infinite loop when I try to run this. I'll edit the post above to show the  code. Could you explain why it does that? <3

Comment: No worries. We all had to start somewhere and that will always be so as technology, languages, and stuff change. My simple philosophy: ***'ABL&I' always be learning and improving.*** Learn from everybody regardless of who they are. Take what is useful, and ignore the rest.

Comment: Agreed! I feel that's a mandatory philosophy to survive in the IT/Dev world. A lot of people I come across stay stagnant and the world moves on without them. 

So, when I try to run it now, I think due to the way the Get-RandoPass function is built since there's nothing to break it after a single input, it keeps asking for how many passwords to generate, at least that's what I think is going on. 

The function will pop up and ask the end user how many passwords to generate and it keeps doing that on loop and I'm not sure how to break it after one run. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The PW thing works against your end goal. Reading a list is not warranted, as You can generate a list using a couple of lines of code.  The way this reads, is that for every SamAccountname you want a list of multiple password offerings? See my update for you for an RPWG.

Comment: This is indeed quite a bit closer to my end goal! The one I had created uses a simple dictionary list to create randomized passphrases which is the endgoal format because obviously I hate end users. We enforce a minimum of 14 characters and passphrases are far better for that than randomized dirty passwords


At anyrate, the format I'm looking for is say Alpha1-Bravo9-Charlie5 but I'll play around with what you wrote above and see if I can figure it out before coming back here for more help!

Comment: So after playing around with it for a little bit, I got it to generate the password format I want by plugging everything in and replacing the $numbers variable with the PasswordCount variable. 

However now it's asking me to supply values for a parameter called Process[0] and if I hit enter it continues and does generate the passwords but if I try to export everything to a csv format it still gives me an error that it can't append the content because the object doesn't have a property that corresponds to the Password column.

EDIT: So for some reason its still looping the pipeline request.

Comment: I just realized, I might well be looping the $passwordcount variable after re-reading that...i think I'm dumb as hell.

Comment: ***;-}*** --- Loops are loops anything in that loop must be executed at least once. If you are calling any other function/code block in that loop, then that has to be executed as well. If you are saying you want to pass in a long list of passwords, then you need to call that once, then if you want to grab a random set from that per user, then you'd use Get-Random on that list, not run the NPR again. See my update for the idea.